# Cannot implicity convert type 'int' to 'string'

Tags: c#, xor

```cs
Random randgen = new Random();
int dkey;
public object SetScore(int val)
{
    dkey=randgen.Next(int.MaxValue/2);
    return val ^ dkey;                //^ means XOR.
}
public string GetScore(int val)
{
    return val ^ dkey;
    GC.Collect();
}
```

From

```cs
public string GetScore(int val)
{
    return val ^ dkey;
    GC.Collect();
}
```

the `return val ^ dkey`  shows the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: `return (val ^ dkey).ToString();`? - And why do you have `GC.Collect();` *after* the return? Everything after the return gets discarded by the compiler, so that line will never be executed.

Comment: Do you want to return a string or an int from GetScore()?

Comment: The compiler error tells you what's wrong. Were you having trouble understanding what the error means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `GetScore` method returns a string, but `val ^ dkey` is an integer. Either convert the result to string with:

```
return (val ^ dkey).ToString();
```

or return an int:

```
public int GetScore(int val) ...
```

Oh, and please remove the call to `GC.Collect()`. It's almost never a good idea to call it yourself. At least it's carefully placed in an unreachable place...

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution:

```
return "" + (val ^ dkey);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (val ^ dkey).ToString()
```