# cannot implicity convert type int to 'string'

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error and don't understand how to fix it

```
  // validate user selected an item
        if(cboCustomerInfo.SelectedIndex >-1)
        {
            // display items in groupbox
            txtLastName.Text = Customers[cboCustomerInfo.SelectedIndex].Excursion;
            if(Customers [cboCustomerInfo .SelectedIndex].Excursion ==1)
            {
                rdoNatureTrail.Checked = true;
            }
            else if (Customers[cboCustomerInfo .SelectedIndex ].Excursion ==1)
            {
                rdoBoatExcursion.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                rdoKayakTour.Checked = true;
            }
            // endable groupbox
            grpNatureExcursion.Enabled = true;

            // set tag group box to index of job
            grpNatureExcursion.Tag = cboCustomerInfo.SelectedIndex;

        }
```

It errors on this statement:

> `txtLastName.Text=Customers[].Excursion`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401578/cs0029-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-int-to-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot implicity convert type 'int' to 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977596/cannot-implicity-convert-type-int-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

what is the method Excursion from customer?? it returns a INT?

well you can cast the result with  .toString();

```
> txtLastName.Text = Customers[cboCustomerInfo.SelectedIndex].Excursion.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

it means exactly what it says, it can't implicitly convert an int to a string. Use ToString() to convert it